# Cant Build iOS Project Using New Machine

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a project created and saved in dropbox from machine x. That machine has since died. Now I am on machine y and downloaded the project workspace. Even after updating the developer certificate, the project still won't build on machine y. It fails with a "Shell Script Invocation Error."

The error I get is:

> /Users/MacUser/Desktop/Projects/ProjectName/Build/ProjectName/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/Script-6729FF60E6114575862B8867.sh: line 2: /Users/MacUser/Desktop/Projects/ProjectName/Pods/Pods-resources.sh: Permission denied

How can I fix this to run the project on my new machine? I can't build to the simulator or device.

Comment: This was it!! Thanks for helping me out